# QGIS clip raster to box

Tags: qgis, raster, clip

I have some merged elevation data which covers a swatch of land. I'd like to clip it so that there are no no-data places. I can't quite seem to come up with an expression to do so. I've drawn a rectangle around what I'd like to accomplish.

[image]

Comment: try clip raster by extent

Comment: Or draw a temporary polygon.

Comment: @GerardoJimenez Ok I did finally get your suggested method working. It seems like I needed to create a shape layer with a polygon to get the correct extents. Is that the right way to do it?

Comment: Clip raster by extent allows you to choose the clipping region by hand in the map canvas

Comment: OMG I see it now. 'Draw on map canvas'. I totally missed it. Thank you very much @GerardoJimenez

Comment: With Save Raster Layer as... (fron TOC - right click menu) you can give the extents by numbers if you want to be exact.